# How to propagate one node to multiple nodes up right and behind each other in Tikz diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, tikz-node

I have drawn the following diagram using Tikz:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 12mm, 
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, 
                 minimum width=22mm, minimum height=5mm, align=center},
            > = {Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]},
   bend angle = 15,
         auto = right,
                        ]
\node (n1)  [box] {text\\ text text text 1};
\node (n2)  [box, below right=of n1]    {text\\ text text 2};
\node (n3)  [box, above right=of n2]    {text\\ text text 3};
%
\draw[dotted,->] (n1) to ["label 1", swap]  (n3);
\draw[dashed,->] (n1) to [bend right, "label 2"]  (n2);
\draw[->]        (n2) to [bend right, "label 3"]  (n1);
\draw[->]        (n2) to [bend right, "label 5"]  (n3);
\draw[dotted,->] (n3) to [bend right, "label 4"]  (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

[image]

My question is: How can I make node `n1` appear like that?

[image]

Comment: `\node [double copy shadow,fill=blue!20,draw=blue,thick] {Hello World!};`, see Ti*k*Z $ PGF manual, page 782. Needed is `shadows` library.

Comment: @Zarko do you happen to have a link for that manual?

Comment: https://texdoc.org/serve/pgfmanual/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me spell-out my comment. For such cases, as you like to have at node `n1`, in Ti*k*Z library `shadows` is defined option `double copy shadow`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                positioning, 
                quotes,
                shadows}  % <--- added

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
   box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=white,
                 minimum width=22mm, minimum height=5mm, align=center},
            > = {Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]},
   bend angle = 15,
         auto = right,
                        ]
\node (n1)  [box,
             double copy shadow={% <--- added
                shadow xshift=1ex, 
                shadow yshift=1ex}] {text\\ text text text 1};
\node (n2)  [box, below right=of n1]    {text\\ text text 2};
\node (n3)  [box, above right=of n2]    {text\\ text text 3};
%
\draw[dotted,->] (n1) to ["label 1", swap]  (n3);
\draw[dashed,->] (n1) to [bend right, "label 2"]  (n2);
\draw[->]        (n2) to [bend right, "label 3"]  (n1);
\draw[->]        (n2) to [bend right, "label 5"]  (n3);
\draw[dotted,->] (n3) to [bend right, "label 4"]  (n2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

[image]